# How can I search for (escape) a dollar sign using ack?

Tags: regex, perl, unix, ack

I want to ack for the literal string: "`$$`" in a code base, but escaping the dollar sign like this:

```
ack \$\$
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `ack '[$][$]'` . Character class. Cleaner than N escapes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are getting confused by shell quoting.  When you type:

```
ack "\\\$\\\$\("
```

the shell interpolates the double quoted string so that `\\` is translated to `\`, `\$` is translated to `$` and `\(` is translated to `\(` and ack gets the string `\$\$\(` as its argument.  It is much simpler to avoid the shell interpolation by using single quotes and invoke:

```
ack '\$\$\('
```

Replace `ack` with `echo` to explore how the shell is expanding the strings.  Note that

```
ack "\\$\\$\("
```

will also work, but for slightly different reasons.  Here, the first two `\` are treated as a single (escaped) `\`, then the `$` is translated as a `$` because it is followed by a character that is not a valid character in a variable name.  `\(` expands to `\(` instead of simply `(` because `(` is not subject to interpolation and therefore does not need to be escaped.  But note that outside of double quotes, `\(` is converted to `(`.

Shell quoting rules get confusing sometimes!

Comment: yeah i get confused by shell quoting rules easily - the echo trick is a great idea though, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 17):

Use ack's `-Q` to do your escaping.

```
ack -Q '$$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the dollar sign character with three backslashes, like this:

```
ack "\\\$\\\$"
```

or use single quotes, where you only have to escape it once:

```
ack '\$\$'
```

Comment: It's much easier to use single quotes: `ack '\$\$\('` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` to take care of the quoting for you by using the `%q` format specifier.

```
$ printf %q '$$('
\$\$\(
```

`help print` has the following to say (I'm assuming bash here)`

```
 %q quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
```